# Zend framework friendly url route router

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a problem with friendly url for my pages in zend.

Now I have next url for moy pages :
http://example.com//info/page/name/about and I need it to be http://example.com/about

I tried to put some code in my Bootstrap.php:

```
$router->addRoute('aboutpage', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('/about' array('controller' => 'info', 'action' => 'about')));
```

but I receive 404 error.

I explored all possibilities and nothing not working for me. Does anybody know what can be a problem ??? Help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$router->addRoute('about', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('about' array('controller' => 'info', 'action' => 'about')));
```

Comment: Not working... try to replace on your suggestion but not working

Comment: Maybe You forgot to add module

Comment: What kind of module? I already have in script 2 routes. They worked. Example:   $router->addRoute('mainpage', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
    '',
    array(
      'controller' => 'index',
      'action' => 'index'
    )
  ));

Comment: Solved :-) problem was in my Bootstrap.php